# Как запустить отладку приложения в QT creator с нужными правами в Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qtcreator

Пишу приложение на С++ которому требуется работать с железом через файлы /dev/… Но после компиляции и запуска все попытки обратится к любому файлу из этой директории завершаются ексепшеном отказа в доступе. Как мне заставить QT запускать вновь скомпилированный файл с необходимыми правами? Либо как мне дать текущему пользователю права делать изменения в файлах в папке /dev. Компилятор GCC 7.3, Ос Kubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вкратце, то запустите qtcreator от root через sudo, тогда все порождаемые процессы будут запущены от root, и, как следствие, будут иметь доступ ко всем устройствам в /dev.

Если сложнее и хочется покопаться, то попробуйте добавить текущего пользователя в одну из групп disk, floppy, tty, video, cdrom, и т.д., которым по умолчанию разрешается доступ к определенному классу устройств, полный перечень групп можно посмотреть /etc/group. Либо попробуйте поиграться с правилами udev на предмет назначения определенной группе из /etc/group неограниченного доступа ко всем устройствам из /dev, а позже добавьте своего пользователя в эту группу.

Comment: Получилось только после переустановки qt из под root'a. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

после компиляции:

```
sudo chown root полный_путь_к_приложению
sudo chgrp root полный_путь_к_приложению
sudo chmod u+s полный_путь_к_приложению
sudo chmod g+s полный_путь_к_приложению
```

У любого пользователя при вызове программы , она будет имеет `root` права.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Права приложению так будут даны но после этого QT не сможет пересобрать проект т.к. у него не будет прав для замены бинарника =)

Comment: пересобрать можно и удалять тоже

Comment: Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Попробовал, QT при попытке сборки выдаёт "Cannot set permissions for /home/mxxxxy/MainProjects/QT_Tmp/untitled/main.cpp to writable.
Could not save the files.". (Перед сборкой обязательно нужно поменять исходны код, иначе переборки не пройзойдёт.)

Comment: Наверное с директорией начудили, надо только экзешнику права

Comment: я только одному бинарнику поменял права, 100%.

Comment: значит собирали qt из роота как советовали другие, тогда всё исправлять права назад надо

Comment: У меня сейчас две сборки. Старая, и собранная из под рута. Сборка собранная из под рута нормально собирает и запускает из под рута, но её саму приходится запускать из под рута. Соответственно всё конфигурирование у неё в рут папках, что не очень. Старая сборка запускает файлы с правами если сделать как вы сказали, но после этого не может пересобрать проект.

Comment: для надёжности посмотрите все права этой папки, затем все файлы в папке `ls -al` скажет, кто на что имеет право

Comment: drwxrwxr-x  3 mrfieldy mrfieldy   4096 июн 25 12:52 .
drwxrwxrwx 12 mrfieldy mrfieldy   4096 июн 25 13:41 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 mrfieldy mrfieldy  44897 июн 22 14:57 CMakeCache.txt
drwxrwxr-x  5 mrfieldy mrfieldy   4096 июн 25 13:03 CMakeFiles
-rw-rw-r--  1 mrfieldy mrfieldy   1574 июн 22 14:57 cmake_install.cmake
-rw-rw-r--  1 mrfieldy mrfieldy   6006 июн 25 12:52 Makefile
-rwsrwsr-x  1 root     root     119224 июн 22 17:04 untitled
-rw-rw-r--  1 mrfieldy mrfieldy   6889 июн 25 12:52 untitled.cbp

Comment: К сожалению не знаю как тут выровнять вывод=(.  И ещё (может это имеет значение) я сделал не совсем как у вас написано а заменил первые две строчки на sudo chown root:root.